# Post all schedule task at once in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pthreads, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have list of scheduled post in database on a particular time. And am using **crontab** to call that function and execute all using **foreach** loop.

**My problem** is let's say i have 10 posts at same time by same user 10:00 am, now the crontab will trigger the event and call the function, here am fetching all 10 posts and passing it to foreach loop.

Now when the last 10th posts is completed time will be 10:10 am, its taking 1 min or less than that to complete one post. now user will think why a post which was scheduled at 10am going at 10:10am ?

I want all posts to at once, Please give me some solutions, i know i need to use **multithreading** concept. Need help on this.

Here is my code, how am doing it.

Under crontab i have this.

`* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Under kernal i have this

```
  {
    $schedule->command('schedule:post')->everyMinute();
  }
```

and under file of Console->Commands->SchedulePost.php

```
   public function handle(PostService $service) 
{   
    $curent_time = Carbon::now();
    $posts = ScheduledPosts::where('status',2)->where('actual_post_time',date('Y-m-d H:i'))->get();
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {

    // here am calling post service which will actually do post
    $post_done = $service->post($user, $newpost->message,$newpost->id);

    }

}
```

Comment: are you inserting anything by  this code 
    $post_done = $service->post($user, $newpost->message,$newpost->id);
?

Comment: @KaushikThakkar, Yes after posting it saves in database.

Comment: Have you tried batch insert ? I think will work for you.